# Como eu Reinicio o apache em um servidor web?

Tags: php, apache

Fiz algumas configurações no php.ini do meu site que não estão funcionando, e me disseram que eu precisava reiniciar o apache para que funcione, porém não sei como proceder com essa reinicialização. Alguém pode me dar um caminho para faze-la?

Comment: No Linux é `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Qual plataforma?

Comment: Clique em [edit] e dê mais detalhes sobre o tipo servidor, se é de terceiros ou não, etc. - se você tem acesso ao php.ini, suponho que tenha acesso ao serviço do apache.

Comment: normalmente numa hosoedagem tem um painel onde pode reiniciar apenas clicando num botão..  Se for o caso de estar numa hospedagem, consulte o suporte da mesma.

Answer (score 1):

> Isso dependo do sistema operacional usado.

### Se tiver acesso ao SSH:

### No CentOS/RHEL

> Se você usa [CPanel](http://cpanel.com/) você provavelmente está usando o CentOS!

```
service httpd restart
```

### No Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Você pode substituir o `restart` por `reload`, ou usar o `reload` antes do `restart` para que os dados de configuração sejam atualizados.

### Se estiver usando "painéis de administração":

### No CPanel/WHM

Você pode usar o [`Restart Services`](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Restart+Services):

```
Home >> Restart Services >> HTTP Server (Apache)
```

### No Plesk 10.x-12.x

Você pode usar o [`Services Management`](https://kb.plesk.com/en/122):

```
[Server >>] Tools & Settings >> Services Management : Web Server (Apache)
```

Nota:
Não faço mais uso do *CPanel* e nunca usei o *Plesk*, por esse motivo não posso afirmar que os dados ainda se mantem correto e está atualizado. Estes dados foram extraídos da página da própria empresa.